# (.NET) Using regex to search through a block of user created html, and insert a query string parameter

Tags: .net, regex, url, replace

I am working on an app where users can create an email template, that could have any number of links in it.  For only those links point specifically to the associated portal site url (which is different in each installation of this app, but stored in the database) I need to insert a new query string key value pair.
The url might already have an existing query string, or it might just end in .com with nothing after.

We won't know the template html ahead, nor how many links or the format of them.

I'm somewhat new to regex but I've been reading a lot and using the regexhero.net tester.  I came up with a pattern that seems to find what I need it to, testing it against a bunch of urls in a block of text with the urls all having different scenarios (caps, spaces, qs, no qs).

```
    Dim Reg As New Regex("<a.*?href\s*=\s*[""'](?<url>.*?)(?<QS>\?.*?)?[""'].*?>.*?</a>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

I'm stuck on is how to do the replace, since it needs to be conditional. 
In the big block of html, insert to the query string only IF the url found contains sSiteUrl ( haven't figured out how to get exact text from a variable into the pattern either)  and insert ?i=123  if it has no query string yet, and &i=123 if it does.

-----[edit] --------------
I'm trying to post in a good example, but it's in html code, and it keeps rendering instead of showing it as html code. I did indent, but that must not be the trick.

I'm going to have a block of html, created by a logged in user and stored in the database.  I'll call that block into a variable on the page. Then I need to find all the

for example href="http://www.portal.com"  needs to become href="http://www.portal.com?i=123"

href="http://www.portal.com/somefolder/landing.aspx?s=code
needs to become
href="http://www.portal.com/somefolder/landing.aspx?s=code&i=123

(It won't actually be 123, but if I can get it inserting that, then i can probably figure out the dynamic bit)

Comment: Please provide the following clearly and concisely: Input and expected output